# Start a progress bar when clicking a button

Tags: unity, c#

This is basically what i am trying to do:

1. Click first scene->Button
2. Start A Progress Bar
3. When the Progress Bar finishes, then...
4. Second Scene->instantiate my Game object

This is my code:

```
// First Scene
public class LoadingScreen : MonoBehaviour  //first scene script
{
    public GameObject slidercanvas;

    public void NextScene()
    {

        StartCoroutine(LoadNextLevel());
    }
    IEnumerator LoadNextLevel()
    {
        slidercanvas.SetActive(true);
        Slider s = slidercanvas.GetComponentInChildren<Slider>();  
        AsyncOperation sceneLoading =SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("ScrollGrids");

        while (!sceneLoading.isDone) 
        {
            float progress = Mathf.Clamp01(sceneLoading.progress / 0.9f);
            s.value = progress; 
            yield return null;

        }
   }

  //second scene

  public class ScrollGridScript : MonoBehaviour
  {
    public static ScrollGridScript Instance;
    public GameObject SpawnPrefab;
    GameObject newobj;
    public GameObject parent;
    Vector3 pos;
    string msgSpeech;
    int counter=0,totalVal;
    public List<GameObject> btns;
   //float progress;

    void Start()
    {
        btns = new List<GameObject>();
        StartCoroutine(Populate());
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (totalVal==counter)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < btns.Count; i++)
            {
                btns[i].SetActive(true);
            }
        }

    }
    IEnumerator Populate()
    {
        //code here(encoding jsonurl)
        StartCoroutine(Downloadimage(newobj, msgSpeech,tname));
        totalVal =  data["categorylist"].Count;
    }

    public void OnButtonclick(string imgname)
    {
        effector.Instance.setEffector(imgname);
        Debug.Log("ButtonId" + imgname);
    }

   IEnumerator Downloadimage(GameObject newobj, string imgUrl, string catid)
   {
      UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(msgSpeech);

      DownloadHandler handle = www.downloadHandler;
      yield return www.SendWebRequest();

      Texture2D texture2d = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);

      if (www.isHttpError || www.isNetworkError)
      {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error while Receiving: " + www.error);
      }
      else
      { 
       counter++;
       newobj = (GameObject)Instantiate(SpawnPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity); 
       newobj.transform.SetParent(parent.transform);
       newobj.transform.localPosition = pos;
       newobj.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => 
       OnButtonclick(catid));  
       Image sprite = newobj.transform.GetComponent<Image>();
       sprite.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2d, new Rect(0, 0, texture2d.width, 
       texture2d.height), new Vector2(0, 0)); //fetch the images from the serve 
       //and convert it
       newobj.SetActive(false);
       btns.Add(newobj);  // instantiate object store in list
    }
}
```

And here is the output I see when I run this code:

[image: Unity console showing several "progress:-0" debug outputs back to back]

Comment: Hi, tbh I dont think its as clear to us as you hoped what you're trying to do.  So you want to click a button and a progress bar to start, and finish.. (why?) and then after that instantiate some object but something to do with a download..

Comment: Please take take the time to proofread your edits to ensure they're having the effect you intend. Visit the [help] if you're having trouble with the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Async Scene Loading. This will try to load the scene and at the same time, you can show the slider. Below is an example script you can use.

1. So when the button is pressed We will start the co-routine by "StartCoroutine(LoadNextLevel())".
2. Then in some scripts inside your "scene2", you should instantiate your game object in the Start() Method Or inside "[SceneManager.sceneLoaded](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html)" delegate

   ```
   // Starts a Progress Bar and Loads the next scene asynchronusly
   IEnumerator LoadNextLevel()
   {
     sliderCanvas.SetActive(true); // show the progess bar
     Slider s = sliderCanvas.GetComponentInChildren<Slider>(); // grab the progress bar slider    
     AsyncOperation sceneLoading = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Scene2");// try to load next scene

     while (!sceneLoading.isDone) // keep increasing the slider value until the next scene is loaded
     {
       float progress = Mathf.Clamp01(sceneLoading.progress / 0.9f);
       s.value = progress; // assign the sliders value with scene load progress
       yield return null;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: sometimer loader complete(1) and some images not fetch and it take too much time

Comment: Sorry, Don't understand you...

Comment: hi shruvo basically what i m doing when first scene click(play) and set a loader but my slider should be fast(0-1)
basically, i am working with url(json) my all data fetch and store in list,sometime not fetch my data so i store in list
when completely fill my list then loader should be finish and display mydata,so what i m do??